# Link javascript file dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to link to a javascript file in header dynamically

```
<script src='<%=Global.RootPath%>js/jquery1.4.2.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='<%=Global.RootPath%>js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but I got an error

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: `System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection
>   cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <%
>   ... %>).`

I want to add javascript file dynamically. Please explain why I am getting this error and is there any other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a common error when you try to render content like that on the header.

You can do alternative thinks like:

Place a literal control, and fully render your script line on code behind.

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" id="txtScripts" EnableViewState="false" />
```

and render the full line on code behind as

```
txtScripts.Text = string.Format(
"<script src='{0}js/jquery1.4.2.js' type=\"text/javascript\"></script>", Global.RootPath);
```

Or alternative you can create them totally dynamically and added to the header control list.

Answer (score 0):

To include a javascript you can also include at the end of document itslef. If you want to specifically insert at the header then create a literal control and set its text to your script tags and add it to Page.Headers.